# Something wrong with my Drag_Enter/Drag_Drop events

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I set two events in my code, Drag_Drop and Drag_Event, and everytime I try to drag something into the form, the 'circle with a line through it' symbol appears. Funny thing is, I used the same exact code in another project, and it worked perfectly. I registered the events and everything. Here is my code:

```
private void Form1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (toSaveIcon)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        }
    }
}

private void Form1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (toSaveIcon)
    {
        string[] filePath = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
        foreach (string path in filePath)
        {
            icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(path);
            Debug.WriteLine("Icon saved successfully");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Set `AllowDrop=true` on the Form1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Funny thing is, I used the same exact code in another project, and it worked perfectly.

I had this issue before, I fixed it by running Visual Studio as a normal user. Make sure it is not running as an `Administrator` if you are running from visual studio.

You can also run the app directly from the `bin` folder , you will have a better idea.

Comment: Thanks, I always run it as admin and I tried not to this time, it worked.